# error using loss_curve_ attribute of MLPClassifier in python

Tags: python-3.x, mlp

I am using MLPClassifier in python and I am trying to use the loss_curve_ attribute but I have this error **"'MLPClassifier' object has no attribute 'loss_curve_' "**. Any ideas of what import I need? I have already tried the "from sklearn import metrics" but it didnt work.

Comment: Can you show slightly more of your code?

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to do so. Eventually I found out that in the MLPClassifier function I had solver="lbfgs", but only the solver="sgd" can give me the losses (loss functionI mean) in every step, and then I can use the .loss_curve_